# create db2 non clustered index

Tags: database, indexing, db2, non-clustered-index

Can you please tell me how to create a nonclustered index in DB2 ?I am not able to find any commands for that. I want to create one index on three columns. I tried:

```
CREATE INDEX IX_ACCOUNTNOTES_DATE_TYPE 
ON CPMTD.ACCOUNT_NS (ACCOUNT_ID,CREATED_DATE,NOTE_TYPE);"
```

Its giving me error as:

```
   DB2 SQL Error: SQLCODE=-104, SQLSTATE=42601, SQLERRMC=;;TED_DATE,NOTE_TYPE );END-OF-STATEMENT,       DRIVER=3.50.152   

    Message: An unexpected token "" was found following "".  Expected tokens may include:  "TED_DATE,NOTE_TYPE )".. SQLCODE=-104, SQLSTATE=42601, DRIVER=3.50.152
```

ALso, create nonclustered index command is not working for db2.

any help will be greatly appreciated.

Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The normal [`CREATE INDEX (DB2 for z/OS)`](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/dzichelp/v2r2/topic/com.ibm.db2z9.doc.sqlref/src/tpc/db2z_sql_createindex.htm#db2z_sql_createindex) or  [`CREATE INDEX (DB2 for LUW)`](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_9.7.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.sql.ref.doc/doc/r0000919.html?cp=SSEPGG_9.7.0%2F2-10-6-72&lang=en) command should be working for you,

```
CREATE INDEX IX_ACCOUNTNOTES_DATE_TYPE 
ON CPMTD.ACCOUNT_NS (
     ACCOUNT_ID
    ,CREATED_DATE
    ,NOTE_TYPE
)
```

If you copied and pasted your command exactly, then the extra `"` on the end there may have been messing things up.

Additionally, DB2 creates all indexes as non-clustered. The exceptions are that the first index defined will be the clustering index, unless you define a new index with the `CLUSTER` option:

```
CREATE INDEX IX_ACCOUNTNOTES_DATE_TYPE 
ON CPMTD.ACCOUNT_NS (
     ACCOUNT_ID
    ,CREATED_DATE
    ,NOTE_TYPE
)
CLUSTER
```